# .htaccess and .htpasswd not working when protecting my site

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a need to password protect an entire website. I am developing on a live URL (don't ask me why -_- clients...) and I want to be able to develop the site but access it using a username and password so the general public won't be able to see the site being modified.

I've tried to use a `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file in the same directory.

Here are the contents of it

```
AuthUserFile /htdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Development space"
AuthType Basic
Require development
```

and the `.htpasswd` file contains the user `development:encryptedpassword`

It doesn't appear to be working at all. The password box is generated but just carries on coming back up once I enter the credentials (I have confirmed they are correct).

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**Please note** both the `htpasswrd` and `htaccess` files are currently within the `htdocs` directory

`htdocs` file permissions are `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: How did you create `htpasswd` file?

Comment: I used http://www.tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/ and just used the `touch` command to create the `.htpasswd` file and entered the generated credentials.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Require` line is wrong. It [should be](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require):

```
Require user development
        ^^^^--missing
```

`Require` can require many different things (env vars, http methods, groups, blah blah blah), so you have to say WHAT kind of thing you're requiring. You might be better off with just

```
Require valid-user
```

unless you're going to have multiple accounts in your .htpasswd and want to allow only certain ones.

Comment: I've changed it to `Require user development` but no success. I have edited my question and don't know if any of that extra info helps?

Comment: Check the server's error log. it'll say why the password was rejected. As well, how did you crypt the password? You say you manually created the file, which doesn't sound good. why not use the command line `htpasswd` utility to do it for you? that way you're guaranteed to get correct info in the file.

Comment: The site is currently on an `ftp` server so I can't use `ssh` commands via the terminal.

Comment: if all you've got is ftp access, you'd need to stuff up a php script to dump out the log for you, or download the log file itself. No idea on your server's config, but generally it'd be something like `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: I had the same problem. I was using `Require myUsername` and changing it to `Require valid-user` fixed it. Many thanks!